# Borda’s positional ranking

Tags: python, algorithm, list, python-2.7

I have tree lists of elements sorted by descending scores. What I need to do is to use [Borda’s positional ranking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_voting_system) to combine ranked lists using information of the ordinal ranks of the elements in each list.Given lists t1, t2, t3 ... tk, for each candidate c and list ti, the score B ti (c) is the number of candidates ranked below c in ti. 
So The total Borda score is B(c) = ∑ B ti (c)
The candidates are then sorted by descending Borda scores.

I tied that, but it does not give the output needed:

```
for i in list1, list2, list3:
   borda = (((len(list1)-1) - list1.index(i)) + ((len(list2)-1) - list2.index(i)) + ((len(list3)-1) - list3.index(i)))
   print borda
```

Can someone help me to implement the above function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling index(i) takes time proportionate to the list size, and because you have to call that for every element, it ends up taking O(N^2) time where N is the list size.  Much better to iterate one list at a time where you know the index and add that part of the score to a score accumulator in a dict.

```
def borda_sort(lists):
    scores = {}
    for l in lists:
        for idx, elem in enumerate(reversed(l)):
            if not elem in scores:
                scores[elem] = 0
            scores[elem] += idx
    return sorted(scores.keys(), key=lambda elem: scores[elem], reverse=True)

lists = [ ['a', 'c'], ['b', 'd', 'a'], ['b', 'a', 'c', 'd'] ]
print borda_sort(lists)
# ['b', 'a', 'c', 'd']
```

The only tricky part here is scanning lists in reverse; this makes sure that if an element was not in one of the lists at all, its score increases by 0 for that list.

Compare with the other suggestion here:

```
import itertools
import random

def borda_simple_sort(lists):
    candidates = set(itertools.chain(*lists))
    return sorted([sum([len(l) - l.index(c) - 1 for l in lists if c in l], 0) for c in candidates], reverse=True)
    # returns scores - a bit more work needed to return a list

# make 10 random lists of size 10000
lists = [ random.sample(range(10000), 10000) for x in range(10) ] 
%timeit borda_sort(lists)
10 loops, best of 3: 40.9 ms per loop

%timeit borda_simple_sort(lists)
1 loops, best of 3: 30.8 s per loop
```

That's not a typo :) 40 *milli*seconds vs 30 seconds, a 750x speedup. The fast algorithm is not significantly more difficult to read in this case, and may even be easier to read, it just relies on an appropriate auxiliary data structure, and going through the data in the right order.

Comment: When I call this code, it gives me the error:  TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: @user3573552: how are you running it? Python version? Complete code?

Comment: @ Alex I See this question  pyhton: Use a list as the key in a dic

Answer (score 0):

This could work:

```
sorted([sum([len(l) - l.index(c) - 1 for l in [list1, list2, list3] if c in l], 0) for c in [candidate1, candidate2, candidate3]], reverse=True)
```

Note that since scores are reordered you'll lose track of which candidate each score belongs to:

```
>>> list1 = ['a', 'c']
>>> list2 = ['b', 'd', 'a']
>>> list3 = ['b', 'a', 'c', 'd']
>>> candidates = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> sorted([sum([len(l) - l.index(c) - 1 for l in [list1, list2, list3] if c in l], 0) for c in candidates], reverse=True)
[5, 3, 1, 1]
```

In this case the first element of the list (the winner) is 'b', the second element in the list of candidates.